# If $a+b|ab, a+c|ac, b+c|bc$ then there is a prime which divides $a,b,c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I wish to show that if $a+b|ab, a+c|ac, b+c|bc$ then there is a prime which divides all of $a,b,c$, where $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

First, I rule out the case that any pair are coprime: in this case, $(a,b)=(ab,a+b)=1$, but now since $a+b|ab$, we must have that $a+b=1$, which forces one of $a$ or $b=0$, contradicting the positivity of $a,b$. This argument works for any pair, so we've ruled out pairwise co-primality.

Thus, we suppose that $(a,b)=d_{ab}$, $(a,c)=d_{ac}$, $(b,c)=d_{bc}$ and WLOG suppose that
$$1<d_{ab}<d_{ac}<d_{bc}$$
(if two are equal, then there is a prime factor of $a,b,c$ and we're done).

I'm having trouble finishing, though. Where can I go from here?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped.

Comment: This is very hard to read. Please use parentheses: $(a+b)|ab$, etc.

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%20%5Cmid%20ab%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bc%20%5Cmid%20ac%24&p=1), I found the AoPS [$(a,b,c)>1$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1785188p11783970) with your problem, and also [$x$, $y$, $z$ are positive integers such that $x + y \mid xy$ and $y + z \mid yz$. Prove that $\gcd(x, y, z) > 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482470/602049) which shows you only actually require $2$ of the $3$ divisibility requirements to reach the stated conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there is no common factor of all of $a,b,c$. As noted by the OP, each pair of these numbers does have a non-trivial gcd.

Let $a=ZU$ and $b=ZV$, where $U$ and $V$ are coprime. Then $Z(U+V)$ divides $Z^2UV$ and so $U+V$ divides $Z=$ gcd$(a,b)$.

The gcd of $b$ and $c$ is coprime to $Z$ and so divides $V$. Similarly,  the gcd of $a$ and $c$ is coprime to $Z$ and so divides $U$.

Hence gcd$(a,b)$ is larger than both gcd$(b,c)$ and gcd$(c,a)$.

We could have started with a different gcd and obtained a different larger gcd. This contradiction proves that there is a common factor of all of $a,b,c$.

Comment: How did you obtain $U+V | Z$? I'm not seeing how that follows from $Z(U+V)|Z^2UV$.

Comment: Since U and V are coprime U+V and UV are necessarily coprime.

Comment: ah, yes, I see! Thank you!